# Get DateTime from monthCalendar control

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, monthcalendar

```
DateTime[] arr=new DateTime[dt.Rows.Count];
for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++){
     arr[i]=Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["datetime"]);
}
this.monthCalendar1.MonthlyBoldedDates = arr;
```

I want on `monthCalendar1_DateChanged` to get the `DateTime`(including the time).
I tried to use `monthCalendar1.SelectionStart` but I get only the date without the time value.

Thanks.

Comment: What control are you using on your front end?  AJAX toolkit?

Comment: What time value would you like to use?  The control won't provide one obviously.

Comment: A calendar shows dates, not times.  Recovering the time from the selection can be done simply with, say, a Dictionary.  Assuming the days are unique, hardly a guarantee.

Comment: dt.Rows[i]["datetime"] contains time, if days are not unique?